# Why do React lifecycle methods return `mixed` and not `void`?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Talking about the types listed here: https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.63.1/lib/react.js#L45-L66

Shouldn't they be returning `void` because they don't `return` anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was because of [Flow issue #1803 "Allow react components' lifecycle methods to be async"](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1803). That means returning a promise should be allowed so that those functions can be asynchronous.

A [Flow TODO issue "Allow React lifecycle methods to return mixed"](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/4886) based on that discussion was created, and [this patch](https://github.com/facebook/flow/commit/2bdbc33b458f8f6165466864b1f59f4428881b75) introduced the change from `void` to `mixed`.

The reasoning (quote)

> This will allow people to write stuff like:
>
> ```
> class Component extends React.Component {
>   async componentDidMount() {
>     // ...
>   }
> }
> ```

The issue could have been solved with a return type of `void | Promise<void>`, but the reason to go with `mixed` is

> It doesn't really seem like the responsibility of Flow to enforce something that does not make a difference at runtime